# WIX: how do conditions for Show Dialog work with properties like VS2010_IDE_VCSHARP_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED?

Tags: visual-studio, properties, wix, conditional-statements

I need to show warning message to user (not Condition Message) based on VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED property value.
Here is simple example:

```
{some files added}
...
<PropertyRef Id="VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

<UI Id="CheckStudio">
  <Dialog Id="StudioDlg" Width="260" Height="75" Title="Hello" NoMinimize="yes" >

    <Control Id="Message" Type="Text" X="10" Y="10" Width="240" Height="40" Text="There is a problem." />

    <Control Id="Return" Type="PushButton" X="110" Y="52" Width="50" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="&amp;OK">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>

  </Dialog>

  <InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="StudioDlg" Sequence="1" >
      <![CDATA[Installed OR VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED]]>
    </Show>
  </InstallUISequence>

</UI>
```

I tried the following conditions:

```
VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED<>""
VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED<>"0"
VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED<>"{value}"
```

But nothing helps. On my both machines (one has VS installed, another one is clean) the dialog appears at the same time (but should be only on the first one). I did make a log and it shows that only on the first machine this property has a value.
Ho do these properties (indicating something) should be used in such conditions? Maybe there is another way?

Comment: Please add declaration of "VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED" property (<Property> tag, not only <PropertyRef>). Probably you are searching for VS 2010 not correctly

Comment: According to MSI log file the property is set correctly: AppSearch: Property: VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED, Signature: SearchForVWD2010ProjectSystemUnderVSSetup
MSI (c) (90:A4) [20:16:22:560]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (90:A4) [20:16:22:561]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED property. Its value is 'webproj'.

Comment: For VS2012 value is totally different:       MSI (c) (90:A4) [20:16:22:562]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VS2012_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Project\'.

Comment: I tried to follow your advise and the result is next: "Duplicate symbol 'Property:VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED' found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem after installing WIX 3.6:

```
<InstallUISequence>
   <Show Dialog="FrameworkDlg" After="CostFinalize" >
     <![CDATA[NOT (Installed OR VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED OR VS2012_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED)]]>
   </Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Installer should warn user that Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 better be installed on the machine before installing.

Answer (score 0):

Then it looks the problem not in property. Please try setting condition to '0' and '1'. Does that make difference? I suppose not. Then check this:

```
  <InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="StudioDlg" Before="WelcomeDlg" >
      <![CDATA[Installed OR VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED]]>
    </Show>
  </InstallUISequence>
```

I changed the sequence to later (before WelcomeDlg). It will be executed after properties initialization. I suppose the property isn't initialized yet at sequence=1.

Comment: Unfortunately Before="WelcomeDlg" produces error and After="CostFinalize" changes nothing. No message during install.